# PHP variable from textbox not passing to email message

Tags: php, html, variables

I am attempting to have an email sent containing a users Username and Password, but the Username *is not* going through, whereas the Password *is*.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))

$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$email_from = 'Me@email.com';
$email_subject = "Username and Password for you";
$email_body = "Username: $user \n". 
"Password: $pass \n".

$to = $email;
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_from \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<form action="db.php" method="post">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username" readonly value='<?php echo $random_first .'_'. $random_second; ?>'><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="password" readonly value='<?php echo $pw; ?>'><BR>
  Enter your email to get a copy of these!<br>
  <input type="text" name="email"><BR>
  <input type ="submit" value = "submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Resulting Email:

```
Username:
Password: hG31cZbTL
```

I am now at a loss. The username generates in the form as it should. I have probably just missed something small and need other eyes to see it.

I have a script that generates a random username and password when the page loads, hence the variables in the username and password values. They are quite long and didn't think that they would pertain to this particular issue, so have left them out.

Comment: Are you sure `<?php echo $random_first .'_'. $random_second; ?>` have values always? because rest of your code looks completely fine.

Comment: can you see values in your `textbox` before submitting it?

Comment: first you can check values of `$random_first , $random_second` .show your code for generate random values

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala Yes, values are in the box before submitting

Comment: @noushidp This code works exactly as it should. It just seems that it can't pull the generated info from the text box.

Comment: @Anant Yes, it always has values.

Comment: This code does not work as it should, it is just working by chance.

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP code to :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) // did changes here
{
   $user = $_POST['username'];
   $pass = $_POST['password'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

   $email_from = 'Me@email.com';
   $email_subject = "Username and Password for you";
   $email_body = "Username: $user \n". 
   "Password: $pass \n".

   $to = $email;
   $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_from \r\n";

   mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: Y so ? whenever subit button will be clicked we will send the message. That is what to be done, and the code is doing the same

Answer (score 0):

should be includecode for generate random variable in html page

**html**

```
<?php 
 require_once 'your file';
 // or code 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

**php**

```
if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['email']))
{
 $user = $_POST['username'];
 $pass = $_POST['password'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace bellow line of with in your code.

```
$email_body = "Username: $user <br/> Password: $pass ";
```

or

```
$email_body = "Username: ".$user." <br/> Password: ".$pass;
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried your suggestions above, but they simply stopped the email being sent at all.

I removed `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))` and it worked perfectly! Go figure.

Thanks for all your input though, I appreciate all your time.

EDIT: Holy cow! OK, for some reason, I did NOT see any of you remove the bang (!) from `if(!isset($_POST['submit']))`.Because the curly brackets kept getting pointed out I just missed the bang altogether, I guess!

I have removed the bang and now it works without issue and is safe from the skynet bots wanting to inundate my server with blank emails that go nowhere.

Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Not sure why my answer would get downvoted if it is the actual resolution. Might not be perfect, but it works.

Comment: If a security guard stops you at a checkpoint to verify your id you prove your id or remove the guard from that check post and leave it unattended and then feel good that the problem is resolved?

Comment: With that check removed, everytime someone loads that page your server will try to send an email. Imagine when a bot comes through and visits your page 100 times in 1 second. You  server tries to send  100 emails with blank data

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't know that. Thanks, I'll take another look.